# How to debug Live GPS and base layer alignment issues in QGIS?

Tags: gps, qgis-2

I am trying to use a bluetooth GPS with a couple of base layers in QGIS. The GPS/bluetooth connection seems to be working great...I can connect and disconnect without issue. I've set my project CRS to WGS84, and I've enabled OTF CRS transformation. I've confirmed the CRS for my base layers is set properly. However, I can't zoom to my base layers to know if my GPS point is lining up where I think it should be with the base layers. Whenever I click 'Zoom to Layer Extent', nothing happens. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

I am using QGIS ver. 2.0.1 on a Windows 8 32-bit tablet.

Comment: On which layer are you trying `Zoom to Extent`? The GPS layer may not have an extent until the data is saved to disk.

Comment: Definitely one of the base layers. As far as I can tell, the GPS is not behaving as a layer. But the extent seems correct for the GPS as it is in decimal degrees. Please forgive me, I am new to QGIS. I am looking for a low cost GPS/mobile GIS solution that can be managed on a tablet. The QGIS software seems to be vert capable, so I'm hoping I've just overlooked a setting somewhere? Thanks...

Comment: What do you use as Base layer? OpenLayers plugin will have the whole world as extent. Try a country shapefile from gadm which will give you a defined extent of your country.

Comment: I was attempting to use base layers (shapefiles) from the state level. They are in UTM10, NAD83. If I unproject the base layers to WGS84 in ArcGIS, and load them into QGIS, the live GPS overlays as expected with the base layers. I would love to make this work without having to reproject first. It seems this may be a projection issue, but I need to determine if it is an issue with my base layers, if there is a bug in the OTF transformation model in QGIS, or perhaps the GIS plugin only works with layers in WGS84. Thanks very much for your suggestion to try a base layer in WGS84!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with OTF in QGIS, it works for me. Please check carefully if all layers have the right CRS assigned using Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer`. In `Settings -> Options -> CRS` tab choose "Ask for CRS of new layers" to make sure QGIS does not silently assign a wrong CRS.

Comment: Andre, are we using different versions of QGIS? The nomenclature within QGIS seems to be a bit different than what you are describing. The properties for my base layer is showing the appropriate CRS - NAD83/UTM10. When I turn on OTF and choose the CRS of WGS84, the extent zooms in to -123,90 - I assume it be be decimal degrees. But, the layer doesn't show and when I try to zoom to extent it does nothing. When I export the layer to shapefile with a CRS of WGS84, and view in ArcGIS, it shows at -123,90, but all of the shapes (points) are stacked on top of one another.

Comment: Andre, I've run one additional test with a base layer in a different CRS - NAD27/UTM10. The OTF is behaving correctly, as you've described. So the problem seems to be with my other base layers...I've tried others that are in NAD83/UTM10, and they all seem to behave the same way, not working. The problem is that the vast majority of my base layers are in this projection. Would you care to look at an example of one to see if we are having the same issue? - Mark

Comment: My QGIS talks German, and has no on-the-fly-translation, so your menu entries may display differently :-) If the extent of your layer is in degrees, it can not be UTM. Try to align it with an openlayers plugin basemap as reference. Project CRS must be EPSG:3857 for that.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the response. I figured out the problem. My base layer is in UTM10N, NAD83, but the units are in feet, not meters. I am guessing that the transformation model that QGIS uses anticipates meters for the units to convert from UTM to DD. So I reprojected in ArcGIS from feet to meters and then brought over to QGIS, and OTF handled it like you said it would. Is there an easy way to set the units in CRS, or would I need to create a new CRS first? Wish I had caught this previously as it would have worked right from the start. Thanks again for working with me through this! - Mark

Comment: Try EPSG:4430. If that does not work, you have to set up a custom CRS with `+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=us-ft +no_defs`.

Comment: @Andre Thanks very much for your input, your suggested CRS worked perfectly! - Mark

Answer (score 1):

Based on troubleshooting tips from Andre, we determined that my issue really had nothing to do with QGIS and CRS OTF not working properly. I was not using the correct transformation parameter for my base layers; this was my problem. Once I figured this out, my live GPS and base layers aligned perfectly. Props to Andre for helping me through this! - Mark